# DRF - How to modify list swagger schema?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to override list response swagger schema:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class CustomPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response_schema(self, schema):
        schema = super().get_paginated_response_schema(schema)
        invoice_sum_schema = {
            'type': 'string',
            'example': '123.45',
        }
        schema['properties']['invoice_sum'] = invoice_sum_schema
        return schema
```

I specified it in view:

```
class PenaltiesView(XLSXFileMixin, ListOnlyModelViewSet):
    ...
    pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination
     
    @swagger_auto_schema(operation_summary='Summary', tags=['TAG1'])
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        ....
```

But the field `invoice_sum` is not being displayed. Method `get_paginated_response_schema` is not even called. How to display the field `invoice_sum`?

I use drf-yasg==1.21.4

Answer (score 1):

Had to write instector:

```
class PenaltiesDjangoRestResponsePagination(PaginatorInspector):
    def get_paginated_response(self, paginator, response_schema):
        paged_schema = None
        if isinstance(paginator, PenaltiesPageNumberPagination):
            has_count = not isinstance(paginator, CursorPagination)
            paged_schema = openapi.Schema(
                type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
                properties=OrderedDict((
                    ('count', openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER) if has_count else None),
                    ('next', openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, format=openapi.FORMAT_URI, x_nullable=True)),
                    ('previous', openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, format=openapi.FORMAT_URI, x_nullable=True)),
                    ('invoice_sum',
                     openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, format=openapi.FORMAT_DECIMAL,
                                    title='Total invoice sum', x_nullable=True)),
                    ('results', response_schema),
                )),
                required=['results']
            )

            if has_count:
                paged_schema.required.insert(0, 'count')

        return paged_schema
```